# How to convert a .xlsx file as a base64 string or byte array into readable string with Java?

Tags: java, csv, gmail-api, xlsx

So I have a program that is parsing attachments using the Gmail API. Most of the attachments come as a plain .csv, which is easy to work with. A few attachments come as an Excel .xlsx file with extra formatting above the csv entries.

When using the Gmail API, the attachment is first returned as a Base64 String. For the .csv attachments, I can then convert it into a byte[] array that is converted into a readable String. The way I understand .xlsx files is that they are a bunch of compressed xml files. When I try converting the base64 into a byte[] array, it gives me a bunch of random symbols.

Is there any simple way of converting a .xlsx file as a byte[] array or base64 String into a readable String, using Java, to be able to parse just the csv contents?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? If I search the web for "load XLSX in java" the very first result already feels like it perfectly covers that problem. Did https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-read-excel-file-in-java not work for you?

Comment: There is no csv inside that you could read. There is some xml that you could theoretically play with, but you're better off using a library for the whole xlsx format. (If you want to see what's inside, rename it to .zip and unpack it...)